# Django forms, field empty error not being raised

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to build a blog with django+xadmin, with using django form to display & validate the username and password.

In `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True,)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=5)
```

In `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
# Create your views here.

from .models import UserProfile
from .forms import LoginForm


class CustomBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(Q(username=username)|Q(email=username))
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Exception as e:
            return None


class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "login.html", {})

    def post(self, request):
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user_name = request.POST.get("username","")
            pass_word = request.POST.get("password","")
            user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pass_word)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return render(request,"index.html")
            else:
                return render(request, "login.html", {"msg": "username or password is uncorrect", })

        else:
            return render(request,"login.html",{"login_form":login_form.errors})
```

When I set a break point at the `if login_form.is_valid():` and I test it with the empty username and password, the required error raised. And when I watch the detail of login_form, the _errors is none. It shouldn't tick this.
What should I change my code to repair this error.

and I have pasted my `login.html` here,  how should I change it.

```
<form action="/login/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group marb20 {% if login_form.errors.username %}errorput{% endif %}">
    <label>UserName</label>
    <input name="username" id="account_l" type="text"  />
</div>
<div class="form-group marb8 {% if login_form.errors.password %}errorput{% endif %}">
    <label>PassWord</label>
    <input name="password" id="password_l" type="password"  />
</div>

<div class="error btns login-form-tips" id="jsLoginTips">{% for key,error in login_form.erroes.items %}{{error}}{% endfor %}{{ msg }}</div>
 <div class="auto-box marb38">

    <a class="fr" href="forgetpwd.html">forget the password？</a>
 </div>
 <input class="btn btn-green" id="jsLoginBtn" type="submit" value="sign_in > " />
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that you have even passed your form to your template from your view. When you call render it should look like this:

```
    render(request,"login.html", {'login_form': login_form})
```

Now if you are using `login_form` correctly in the template like so:

```
    <div class='form-group'>
        {{login_form.username}}
        {{login_form.password}}
    </div>
```

That will handle your errors for you and display them. If you want more fine grained control you could do this:

```
{% for field in login_form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you can modify around each individual element. Please read this for more information on form rendering and this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options

**EDIT:**

```
    <form action="/login/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group marb20 {% if login_form.errors.username %}errorput{% endif %}">
    {{login_form.username}}        
</div>
<div class="form-group marb8 {% if login_form.errors.password %}errorput{% endif %}">
   {{login_form.password}}
</div>

<div class="error btns login-form-tips" id="jsLoginTips">{% for key,error in login_form.erroes.items %}{{error}}{% endfor %}{{ msg }}</div>
 <div class="auto-box marb38">

    <a class="fr" href="forgetpwd.html">forget the password？</a>
 </div>
 <input class="btn btn-green" id="jsLoginBtn" type="submit" value="sign_in > " />
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: I have copied my html file above, what should I do to change it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made changes to your posted `.html` to get you started.  You need to READ the link I posted.  All of the answers are in there for you and more.  You may have to take a couple steps back and start with a simpler template.  This way you can incrementally get the result you want.  Especially if you are unfamiliar with django. Test, code, test, code, etc.

My example template in my OP is exactly what you should be starting with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, when I click the sig_in button with set the username and password blank, It has shown the error message.But In the debug model, the _errors remains None. I'll look the document. Thank you

Comment: @AlexKIe if this solved your problem please mark this answer as the solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass just **login_form** as shown below if form is not valid. Because you are accessing **login_form.errors.username** in your template.

```
def post(self, request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if login_form.is_valid():
        ....
    else:
        return render(request,"login.html",{"login_form":login_form})
```

Comment: Just change the render function parameter to what I have shown above. Make it login_form instead of login_form.errors

Comment: I'm sorry, This way doesn't work well with me,  there is nothing error message output.  And the forms valid is none